# how to handle URL request in php like express js does

Tags: php, url, request

I want to handle all URL requests manually like express js in node.js does. And I don't want to use any library because I want to learn and extend my knowledge.

```
if( url === "/profile") //... load profile.php file
```

*This is just a common use case. But if we manage to get all requests in a specific file, then They can be filtered with method and that's will be great for API endpoint handling.*

If I use .htaccess in apache to redirect all request in a base file and then handle it, It will cause some problems, like
htaccess rewrite is not enabled in all sever by default
and that could be a problem in nginx server
and many more ...

I want to do it without any server configuration.

My questions are
Is it possible with only php? I mean without server configuration.
**How php itself handle a request**?

Please help with this problem

Comment: One way to do it is to create subfolders on your server. In your example you will need to create a subfolder named `/profile/` and in that subfolder you add an `index.php` file that manages the request. A little bit clumpsy perhaps, but works...

Comment: Try `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` this will show you (amongst other things) the values for the superglobal arrays. In the $_SERVER array you'll find the values you are looking for along with lots of other useful stuff. However as Gowire says, maybe you should learn the simple stuff before attempting to write your own frontcontroller/router.

Comment: @Gowire That will work fine but is not suitable for a large application I mean that requires lots of work and I don't want to do it. because all requests in a single file will be time-saving and much clear. I believe that there is a way to do it. l Please check my question again I edited it to be more clear.